# Twilio SMS End-to-End-Encryption

Tags: security, twilio, sms, end-to-end-encryption

Is it possible to encrypt an SMS message sent to Twilio? For example, if the client (say iOS device) wants to send a sensitive SMS message to my Twilio application is there a way to encrypt the message on the client before reaching the carrier and decrypt the message when it gets to my backend & vice-versa.

The goal is to prevent the carrier from being able to read the message. I see there are solutions using [Twilio Programmable Chat and Virgil Security](https://virgilsecurity.com/blog/end-to-end-encryption-for-twilio), however, it doesn't handle SMS use cases.

If not possible what's the best workaround using SMS? I'm starting to think if a message is sensitive you shouldn't use SMS under any circumstances. Hoping I'm wrong though.

Any information helps! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

SMS doesn't support encryption, this is the case regardless of the carrier.

You could look at channels such as WhatsApp which is encrypted between the customers WhatsApp client and Twilio. You can then look at Twilio features such as [message body redaction](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/privacy-message-redaction#how-redaction-works-smsmms) for further security.

Another option is to build on Twilio Conversations, and create an App for Android/iOS that the client can use to communicate to you and encrypted between the client and Twilio. You can encrypt the contents of the conversations so that only you and the client can decode the payload. You will build that on top of Twilio Conversations.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your prompt response!